# Вывод в текстовый файл начального значения слов и результата обработки через '='

Tags: c++

Код вывода из файла:

```
char str_1[80];
FILE *f1;
f1=fopen("C:\\text.txt","r");

 if (f1==NULL) 
      puts("error");
 else
   {
        while(!feof(f1))
            {fgets(str_1,25,f1);
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(str_1);i++)
        {
        //код обработки
        {

              puts(str_1);}
              fclose(f1);
    }
```

Я хочу, чтобы выводилось нечто вида 'Слово' = 'Результат обработки', а не только результат обработки - str_1
Как мне сделать, чтобы запоминалось начальное значение переменной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

заведите еще одну переменную, например char str_0[80] и перед циклом вызвать strcpy(str_0, str_1)
Тогда в str_0 будет строка до обработки

Comment: спасибо, помогло